# A simple Snakes and Ladders implementation in Java

Tags: java, game

I created a pretty straight forward snakes and ladders implementation in Java just for the heck of it.
The program can be summed up as-

1. Object of Board contains an array of Type Tile to represent the actual board.
2. Object of type Tile contains an Enum data member to identify if its a regular tile or a snake/ ladder.

   Also contains a destination tile to identify the snake/ ladder destination.
3. Player object contains the player name and player position.
4. On initialization, through randoms, I generate random tiles to be snakes and ladders. Then the user is asked to enter no. of players, and then keep rolling the dice till a player reaches the 100th tile.

### The code:

#### Class `BoardImpl`:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class BoardImpl implements Board{

    Tile[] board = new Tile[101];         //A array to represent the 'board'
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    Set<Integer> occupiedPositions = new HashSet<>();

    public void setPlayers(List<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }

    public Tile[] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void addPlayers(Player player) {
        this.players.add(player);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize() {
//this function generates the board, placing random snakes and ladders and
//filling the rest with normal tiles
        System.out.println("Initializing board");

        int snakes = secureRandom.nextInt(15) + 1; //generates snakes & 
        int ladders = secureRandom.nextInt(15) + 1; //ladders at random
                                                    //positions
        setSnakes(snakes);
        setLadders(ladders);

        for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++){
            if(board[i] != null){
                continue;
            }
            Tile t  = new TileImpl(TileType.NORMAL);
            board[i] = t;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void movePlayer(Player player, int places) {
        int currentPosition = player.getPosition();
        String checkPos = checkEndingPosition(currentPosition, places);
        if(checkPos.equals("winner")){
                winner(player);
        }
        if(checkPos.equals("outOfBoard")){
            System.out.println("That move cannot be made from your position! " +
                    "Roll a different number next time");
        }
        if(checkPos.equals("valid")){
                Tile t = getTile(currentPosition + places);
                if(t.getType().equals(TileType.NORMAL)){
                    player.setPosition(currentPosition + places);
                    System.out.println("Player " + player.getName() +
                            " moves to position "+ player.getPosition());
                }else {
                    player.setPosition(t.getDestination());
                    System.out.println(" Player " + player.getName() +
                            " encountered a "+ t.getType()+ "!!, moves to position "+ player.getPosition());
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Tile getTile(int n) {
        return board[n];
    }

    public String checkEndingPosition(int currentPosition, int places){

        if((currentPosition + places) > 100){
            return "outOfBoard";
        }else if((currentPosition+ places) == 100){
            return "winner";
        }
        else{
            return "valid";
        }
    }

    public void winner(Player player){

        System.out.print("Player " + player.getName() + " has won the game !");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void setSnakes(int n){
//this function generates snakes at random positions
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
            boolean flag = true;
            int start = 0;
            int dest = 0;

            while(flag) {
                 start = secureRandom.nextInt(98);
                if(!occupiedPositions.contains(start)){
                    occupiedPositions.add(start);
                    break;
                }
            }

            while(flag) {
 //Setting the destination for a snake tile to lower than its position
                 dest = (int)(start * secureRandom.nextDouble());
                if(!occupiedPositions.contains(dest)){
                    occupiedPositions.add(dest);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Tile tile = new TileImpl(TileType.SNAKE, dest);
            board[start] = tile;

            System.out.println("Created snake " + "[" + start+ "," + dest + "]");
        }

    }

    public void setLadders(int n) {
//this function generates ladders randomly
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            boolean flag = true;
            int start = 0;
            int dest = 0;

            while (flag) {
                start = secureRandom.nextInt(80);
                if (!occupiedPositions.contains(start)) {
                    occupiedPositions.add(start);
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (flag) {
//this step places the destination for the ladder tile to greater than its position
                dest = (int) (start + secureRandom.nextDouble() * 10);
                if (!occupiedPositions.contains(dest)) {
                    occupiedPositions.add(dest);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Tile tile = new TileImpl(TileType.LADDER, dest);
            board[start] = tile;
            System.out.println("Created ladder " + "[" + start+ "," + dest + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Class `PlayerImpl`:

```
public class PlayerImpl implements Player{


    private int position = 0;
    private String name = null;

    public PlayerImpl(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(int currentPosition) {
        this.position = currentPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String playerName) {
        this.name = playerName;
    }
}
```

#### Class `TileImpl`:

```
public class TileImpl implements Tile {

    private TileType type;
    private int position;
    private int destination;

    public TileImpl(TileType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public TileImpl(TileType type, int dest) {
        this.type = type;
        this.destination = dest;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public int getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setType(TileType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void setDestination(int destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    @Override
    public TileType getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

#### Class `SnakesAndLadders`:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SnakesAndLadders {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Board board = new BoardImpl();
        List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("How many players ?");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int noOfPlayers = scan.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < noOfPlayers; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter name for player "+ i);
            String name = scan.next();
            Player player = new PlayerImpl(name);
            players.add(player);

        }

        board.initialize();
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Lets Play!");
        String choice = "";
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
//simulating a game through the do while loop
        do{
            if(counter >= noOfPlayers) counter = 0;
            Player currPlayer = players.get(counter);
            System.out.println(" Player " + currPlayer.getName() + " turn to play!");
            System.out.println(" R = Roll the dice, Q = quit");
            choice = scan.next();
            if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("R")){
                int places = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
                board.movePlayer(currPlayer, places);
                counter++;

            }
        }while(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));
    }
}
```

I think the game is very straight forward. I wanted to particularly know if

1. There is a better way to generate the random numbers of snakes and ladders.
2. A better and more appropriate data structure to represent the 'board'
3. If my code can be improved to contain any important paradigms/practices.

Comment: `SecureRandom` is *absolute overkill* for this. It is a cryptographical secure random number generator...that means that it draws from the OS pool of secure random numbers, which can be depleted. You want `Random`, and it has the upside that you can initialize it with a seed, which means that games become reproducible, which is good news for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review. Nice implementation and good structure of the code, find my suggestions in line.

> 1. There is a better way to generate the random numbers of snakes and
>    ladders.

The methods `setSnakes` and `setLadders` differ by just a couple of lines of code, which is an indicator of code duplication. This is the method `setLadders`:

```
public void setLadders(int n) {
//this function generates ladders randomly
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        boolean flag = true;
        int start = 0;
        int dest = 0;

        while (flag) {
            start = secureRandom.nextInt(80);
            if (!occupiedPositions.contains(start)) {
                occupiedPositions.add(start);
                break;
            }
        }

        while (flag) {
//this step places the destination for the ladder tile to greater than its position
            dest = (int) (start + secureRandom.nextDouble() * 10);
            if (!occupiedPositions.contains(dest)) {
                occupiedPositions.add(dest);
                break;
            }
        }

        Tile tile = new TileImpl(TileType.LADDER, dest);
        board[start] = tile;
        System.out.println("Created ladder " + "[" + start+ "," + dest + "]");
    }
}
```

One approach is to create a method to generate the random numbers and then use it to generate ladders and snakes. For example:

```
private void setRandomLadder() {
    while (true) {
        int[] segment = getRandomSegment(1,99);
        int start = segment[0];
        int end = segment[1];
        if (isTileFree(start) && isTileFree(end)) {
            board[start] = new TileImpl(TileType.LADDER, end);
            board[end] = new TileImpl(TileType.OCCUPIED);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This method can be invoked `n` times depending on how many ladders you want to add to the board. The method `getRandomSegment` returns two random points between 1 and 99. Also I changed the name from `setLadders` to `setRandomLadder`, to make it self-descriptive. Finally, keep in mind that if you add too many ladders such methods never complete, so consider to check if there are free tiles before.

---

> 2. A better and more appropriate data structure to represent the 'board'

By using the previous method, we can remove the list `occupiedPositions`, which was possible by adding `TileType.OCCUPIED`.

The array of `Tile` is ok as data structure, an alternative is to use `ArrayList`.

---

> 3. If my code can be improved to contain any important
>    paradigms/practices.

- **Console output**:

  ```
  How many players ?
  2
  Enter name for player 0
  ```

  It's confusing for the user to see player 0, start from player 1.
- **Magic numbers**: `new Tile[101]`, `secureRandom.nextInt(98)`, etc. Create constants, for example:

  ```
  private static final int SIZE = 101;
  ```
- **Modifiers**: the methods `setSnakes` and `setLadders` should be private, same for all the instance variables.
- **Initialize in the constructor**: the `BoardImpl` has a method `initialize()` but and empty constructor. You can use directly the constructor.
- **Encapsulation**: the interface `Board` accepts a `Player` with a public `setPosition`, which means anyone can change it. Only the board should change the state of the player. A safer interface might be:

  ```
  public interface Board {
    void movePlayer(String playerId, int places);
    //..
  }
  ```
- **Avoid temporary variables**: instead of

  ```
  Tile tile = new TileImpl(TileType.LADDER, dest);
  board[start] = tile;
  ```

  You can write:

  ```
  board[start] = new TileImpl(TileType.LADDER, dest);
  ```
- **Code smell**:

  ```
      public String checkEndingPosition(int currentPosition, int places){

        if((currentPosition + places) > 100){
            return "outOfBoard";
        }else if((currentPosition+ places) == 100){
            return "winner";
        }
        else{
            return "valid";
        }
    }
  ```

  Returning a String is very error prone here. For example, you could return a boolean and eventually an exception.
- **Testing and reusability**: the method `winner` calls `System.exit(0)`, which makes it impossible to test. Additionally, there are many `System.out.println` in the `BoardImpl` class. It is very hard to test a class like that. Ideally, the class `Board` should never print to the user, only for debugging. The `main` should be responsible to interact with the user.

Answer (score 3):

### Readability and style

Please run your code through a formatter to make it more readable and follow standards.

This one may work:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm

### Flag?

```
            boolean flag = true;
            int start = 0;
            int dest = 0;

            while (flag) {
                start = secureRandom.nextInt(80);
                if (!occupiedPositions.contains(start)) {
                    occupiedPositions.add(start);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

You're not using, checking or changing the flag here. This loop should just be `while(true)` and the next loop does the same thing.

### If-else-

```
if(checkPos.equals("winner")){
                winner(player);
        }
```

When you're checking several exclusive cases and comparing to a string, I think a `switch` statement is a more appropriate/standard way of doing it. It also makes it clearer that the cases are exclusive.

### Data structure

```
Set<Integer> occupiedPositions = new HashSet<>();
```

This seems unnecessary/unnatural to me. I would add to the Tile class a `bool` to mark a tile as occupied, and then that information can be contained in the tile/board itself instead of having a separate `Set` for bookkeeping.